# How can I add Stripe in flutter mobile app (Multi Vendor)

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I want to add stripe in my flutter app. Basically, I'm working on Doctors patients app.
There are multiple doctors and patients. I have worked on one-to-one payment. I can't use each doctor stripe public key or private key for payment. So how can I do that?
Please help me.

Comment: This may help you: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide

Comment: Have you created Connect Accounts for your Doctors? Do you want to pay multiple Doctors for the same patient? what @DrashtiKheni suggested might be what you're looking for depending on what you're actually trying to achieve. It might help if you elaborate more on your use case.

Comment: @Tarzan My case is similar to Uber. In Uber, there are multiple drivers and riders. It is same in my case, multiple doctors and multiple patients.

Comment: I suggest you start by reading more about Stripe [Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect). Whether you need to create [Direct](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges), [Destination](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges) or [Separate](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide) Charges it's really up to the business model you want to put in place.